# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

here is the complete code:

```
stat = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ExcelTable.PayorBankRoutNo, ExcelTable.Amount, ExcelTable.AccountNo, ExcelTable.SerialNo, ExcelTable.PresentingBankRoutNo, ExcelTable.PresentmentDate FROM ExcelTable WHERE ExcelTable.CreationDate = ? INNER JOIN (SELECT PayorBankRoutNo, Amount, AccountNo, SerialNo FROM ExcelTable GROUP BY PayorBankRoutNo, Amount, AccountNo, SerialNo HAVING (count(PayorBankRoutNo) > 1) AND (count(Amount) > 1) AND (count(AccountNo) > 1) AND (count(SerialNo) > 1)) dup ON ExcelTable.PayorBankRoutNo = dup.PayorBankRoutNo AND ExcelTable.Amount = dup.Amount AND ExcelTable.AccountNo = dup.AccountNo AND ExcelTable.SerialNo = dup.SerialNo ORDER BY ExcelTable.SerialNo");
            stat.setString(1, dateName);
            rs = stat.executeQuery();
            metadata = rs.getMetaData();
            li_cols = metadata.getColumnCount();
            allRows = new Vector();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Vector newRow = new Vector();
                for(int i=1; i<= li_cols; i++)
                {
                    newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }
                allRows.addElement(newRow);
            }fireTableStructureChanged(); 

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error "+e);
        }
    }
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return li_cols;
    }
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return allRows.size();
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int aRow, int aCol)
    {
        row = (Vector)allRows.elementAt(aRow);
        return row.elementAt(aCol);
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int col)
    {
        return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public String getColumnName(int aCol)
    {
        return columnNames[aCol];
    }
    String[] columnNames = {"PAYORBANKROUTNO", "AMOUNT", "ACCOUNTNO", "SERIALNO", "PRESENTINGBANKROUTNO", "PRESENTMENTDATE"};
}
```

Comment: -1 for bad codez format.

Comment: Another -1 for bad code format

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more detail. Can you update your question with at least the following: 1) Stacktrace 2) Code where the Exception occurs.

Comment: This question assumes searching for a bug in a myriad of bad code. SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: i've edited it. pls help me check:

Comment: please share the stack trace buddy, and the whole code, I think the issue is about after this command :)

Comment: `here is the complete code:` -> be sure that isn't, or are you joking, is there reason for jokes of this nature

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can't possibly be answered. We have no idea where the error occurs or what your TableModle looks like.

Why are you creating a custom TableModel?  I would guess the problem is because you implemented the model incorrectly.

See the `Table From Database Example` code found in [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a simple example that shows you how to use the DefaultTableModel.